# Twisted - how to make lots of Python code non-blocking

Tags: wamp, twisted, autobahn, twisted.internet, crossbar

I've been trying to get this script to perform the code in `hub()` in written order.

`hub()` contains a mix of standard Python code and requests to carry out I/O using Twisted and Crossbar.

However, because the Python code is blocking, reactor doesn't have any chance to carry out those 'publish' tasks. **My frontend receives all the published messages at the end.**

1. This code is a massively simplified version of what I'm actually dealing with. The real script (`hub()` and the other methods it calls) is over 1500 lines long. Modifying all those functions to make them non-blocking is not ideal. I'd rather be able to isolate the changes to a few methods like `publish()` if that's possible to fix this problem.
2. I have played around with terms like `async`, `await`, `deferLater`, `loopingCall`, and others. I have not found an example that helped yet in my situation.

**Is there a way to modify `publish()` (or `hub()`) so they send out the messages in order?**

```
from autobahn.twisted.component import Component, run
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

component = Component(
    transports=[
        {
            u"type": u"websocket",
            u"url": u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws",
            u"endpoint": {
                u"type": u"tcp",
                u"host": u"localhost",
                u"port": 8080,
            },
            u"options": {
                u"open_handshake_timeout": 100,
            }
        },
    ],
    realm=u"realm1",
)

@component.on_join
@inlineCallbacks
def join(session, details):
    print("joined {}: {}".format(session, details))

    def publish(context='output', value='default'):
        """ Publish a message. """
        print('publish', value)
        session.publish(u'com.myapp.universal_feedback', {"id": context, "value": value})

    def hub(thing):
        """ Main script. """
        do_things
        publish('output', 'some data for you')
        do_more_things
        publish('status', 'a progress message')
        do_even_more_things
        publish('status', 'some more data')
        do_all_the_things
        publish('other', 'something else')

    try:
        yield session.register(hub, u'com.myapp.hello')
        print("procedure registered")
    except Exception as e:
        print("could not register procedure: {0}".format(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run([component])
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `join()` function is async (decorated with `@inlineCallbacks` and contains at least one `yield` in the body).

Internally it registers function `hub()` as WAMP RPC; `hub()` is however not async.

Also the calls to `session.publish()` are not yielded as async calls should be.

Result: you add a bunch of events to the eventloop but don't await them until you flush the eventloop on application shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function hub and publish async.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def publish(context='output', value='default'):
    """ Publish a message. """
    print('publish', value)
    yield session.publish(u'com.myapp.universal_feedback', {"id": context, "value": value})

@inlineCallbacks
def hub(thing):
    """ Main script. """
    do_things
    yield publish('output', 'some data for you')
    do_more_things
    yield publish('status', 'a progress message')
    do_even_more_things
    yield publish('status', 'some more data')
    do_all_the_things
    yield publish('other', 'something else')
```